# getElementsByTagName() in Python's xml.dom.minidom is not working

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

I am parsing an output XML file generated from gtest. I want to find the result of each test case. A test case is failed only when "testcase" has element "failure" otherwise test case is passed. But I could not access  element.

My xml file :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites tests="11" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" timestamp="2015-03-23T17:29:43" time="1.309" name="AllTests">
  <testsuite name="AAA" tests="4" failures="0" disabled="0" errors="0" time="0.008">
    <testcase name="BBBB" status="run" time="0.002" classname="AAA" />
      <failure message="Value of: add(1, 1)&#x0A; Actual: 3&#x0A;Expected: 2" type="" />
    <testcase name="CCC" status="run" time="0.002" classname="AAA" />
    <testcase name="DDD" status="run" time="0.002" classname="AAA" />
    <testcase name="FFF" status="run" time="0.002" classname="AAA" />
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

My python file is :-

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("output.xml")
testsuites = DOMTree.documentElement 
testCaseCollection = testsuites.getElementsByTagName("testcase")
testCasefailure = testsuites.getElementsByTagName("failure")

OutputXLS = open_workbook('output.xls')

for testCase in testCaseCollection:

        #print testCase.firstChild;
        if testsuites.getElementsByTagName("failure"):
                print testCase.getAttribute("name"), " --> ","FAIL"
        else:
                print testCase.getAttribute("name"), " --> ","PASS"
```

And output is :-

```
BBB -->  PASS
CCC  -->  PASS
DDD  -->  PASS
FFF  -->  PASS
```

Though test case "BBB" is failed as it has "failure" attribute in xml, it shows pass in result.
Kindly Help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = parse("output.xml")
testsuites = DOMTree.documentElement 
testCaseCollection = testsuites.getElementsByTagName("testcase")

OutputXLS = open_workbook('output.xls')

for testCase in testCaseCollection:
    sibNode = testCase.nextSibling.nextSibling
    if sibNode and sibNode.nodeName == 'failure':
        print testCase.getAttribute("name"), " --> ","FAIL"
    else:
        print testCase.getAttribute("name"), " --> ","PASS"
```

Comment: Nizam:- what is the logic behind "testCase.nextSibling.nextSibling"?

Comment: testCase.nextSibling refers to content of testcase element. testCase.nextSibling.nextSibling refers to its sibling if it has one.